# Cannot access variable through JavaScript - scope error?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have some data in a separate `.js` file similar to this:

```
data = new Object();
data['cat'] = ['Mr. Whiskers','Wobbles'];
data['dog'] = ['Toothy'];
data['fish'] = ['goldy','roose'];

function getStuff(info)
{
  var stuff = data[info.value];
  return stuff;
}
```

Now in another html file with a block, I have something like this:

```
function theDrop(dynamic) {
  alert(getStuff(dynamic));
}
```

The box says `undefined`, why?

Comment: Your syntax is invalid - `alert(getStuff(dynamic));`

Comment: I realized that and just fixed it. This is just sample code that I wrote, and is not my actual code - it's for a class and I'm not supposed to share it outright. It alerts fine, but alerts as undefined, not as it should.

Comment: how is `theDrop` being called?

Comment: It is called as an onChange method when a drop down is changed.

Comment: I'm assuming the other js file is included in the html file with `theDrop` ?

Comment: If I paste that code into a console and invoke it by calling `theDrop({value:'cat'});`, I get an alert with "Mr. Whiskers,Wobbles".

Comment: Are you sure the dynamic variable has a property called value? This is not a scope error, so search in other directions. For starters just output the various variables you are using to make sure they are what you think they are.

Comment: The first block of code is an included .js file as such: <script src="data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  The second block is an embedded block of code in the head of an HTML file.

Comment: @Naoto check out my answer I think the problem is you are passing the value and not the object, so `.value` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ariel, if I output the variables in the included .js file, it works fine. If I output it in the embedded code where I need it to, it is undefined. That is why I believe it is a scope issue.

Comment: It would really be constructive to tell us in what context you call theDrop and also if the other two methods are defined globally available when theDrop is called. Otherwise we'll just be guessing at the answer. But hey, who doesn't like guessing games right!?

Comment: b01 - an answer has been found already. But to clarify, as I said previously, theDrop was called in an onChange function when a drop down / select had an option chosen. I also stated where the functions were used (one inline, one included). Sorry if that wasn't clear enough to you, but I'm glad you enjoyed the guessing games.

Answer (score 3):

What are you passing to `theDrop`? If you want to call the `.value` then you need to pass the whole object over otherwise you will get `undefined`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/ETQn7/2/)**

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectme");

select.onchange = function(){
    theDrop(this);
}

data = new Object();
data['cat'] = ['Mr. Whiskers','Wobbles'];
data['dog'] = ['Toothy'];
data['fish'] = ['goldy','roose'];

function getStuff(info)
{
    var stuff = data[info.value];
    return stuff;
}

function theDrop(dynamic) {
    alert(getStuff(dynamic));
}
```

Comment: It turns out, you were correct fundamentally - I was indeed passing the .value and not the object itself. Alerting dynamic.value gets what I needed. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Naoto If this answers your question you might consider accepting this as the answer.